# ploting the graph of 1/z for a given value

Tags: plotting, complex, visualization

I want to plot the graph of ${1}/{z}$ , for a specific single value of |z| (z - complex variable) .
I would like something like

```
ConrourPlot[Evaluate[1/(x+ y I], {x,-10,10}, {y,-10,10}, 
RegionFunction->Function[{x,y,z} , x^2+y^2=5]]
```

is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: I'm assuming you just typed that "example code" up on the fly, because it's full of syntactical errors and is nowhere near runnable. When providing code, please make sure that it's at least code that people can run, even if it doesn't what you intend it to do. Otherwise, how is anyone to know whether your problem might simply be solved by correcting the trivial typos?

Comment: What do you mean by "the graph of $1/z$"? (That would be a subset of 4-dimensional real space.) And you say you want to plot for a "single value of $\|z\\$; are you simply asking to plot the *image* in the plane of the circle $\|z\| = r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  f[r_, t_] := ReIm[Exp[-I t]/r]
  Manipulate[
     Row[{
        PolarPlot[radius, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, ImageSize -> 300,
        Epilog -> {Red,PointSize[0.04],Point[ReIm[radius Exp[I angle]]]}, 
        PlotLabel -> Row[{"|z|=", radius}, BaseStyle -> 20]],
        ParametricPlot[f[radius, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True, 
        PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, PlotLabel -> Style["1/z", 20], 
        ImageSize -> 300,Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], 
        Point[f[radius, angle]]}]
        }],
{{radius, 5}, Range[0.2, 0.9, 0.1]~Join~Range[5]},
{angle, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

or,

```
z[r_, t_] := ReIm[r Exp[I t]];
ppz = ParametricPlot[z[r, t], {r, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[u]], 
   MeshFunctions -> (#3 &),
   Mesh -> {Range[0.2, 0.9, 0.1]~Join~Range[5]}, 
   MeshShading -> {Automatic}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
ppf = ParametricPlot[f[r, t], {r, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[u]], 
   MeshFunctions -> (#3 &),
   Mesh -> {Range[0.2, 0.9, 0.1]~Join~Range[5]}, 
   MeshShading -> {Automatic}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
Manipulate[
 Row[{Show[ppz, Graphics[Point[loc]]],
   Show[ppf, 
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
      Point[ReIm[1/(#1 + I #2)] & @@ loc]}]]}],
 {loc, {-5, -5}, {5, 5}, Locator, Appearance -> "\[FilledDiamond]"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function has a real and an imaginary part, so you presumably wish to plot both:

```
ContourPlot[
 ReIm[1/(x + y I)], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10},
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 < 5]]
```

Moreover, I presume you wish your `RegionFunction` to be a disk (not a circle).

[image]

I don't understand why you want to plot between -10 and 10 on each axis when your region function is so much smaller... but that's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of picture you're trying to create?

[image]

If so, by using David Park's *Presentations* add-on, you may create it from:

```
With[{r = 1/2, f = 1/# &},
   circ = ComplexCurve[r Exp[I \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}];
   GraphicsRow[{
      Draw2D[{circ}, PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.4]],
      Draw2D[{circ // ComplexMap[f]}, PlotRange -> 3, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> Scaled[0.4]]
   }]
]
```

Of course this sort of graphic may be also created directly using only built-in *Mathematica* functions (which *Presentations* calls behind the scenes).